# How to enable cmd+click (intellisense) & go to any function in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I code both on imac and macbook. There's nothing wrong when coding on macbook, i can cmd+click to any function and navigate.

The problem is with my imac, i have checked & make sure both my imac and macbook has the same vs code version & settings.

Comment: I'm sure you checked this but ….   "editor.links": true,

Comment: Do both installations also have the same extensions? Extensions implement the functionality this kind of interaction.

Comment: Maybe check your navigation setup. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved